# Singleton realization in Selenium [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, singleton, python-behave

i'm trying to use a Singleton pattern for project with Selenium and Behave, but it doesn't work correctly -  object is always created  second time under @then decorator. I guess i've made some mistake in **new** method, but can't really see where.

```
class WebDriver:
    singleton_instance = None
    driver = None

    def __init__(self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")



    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.singleton_instance = super(WebDriver, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.singleton_instance

@given ("website '{url}'")
def website_opener(context,url):
    driver = WebDriver()
    print(driver.singleton_instance)

@then("push button with text '{text}'")
def button_pusher(context,text):
   driver = WebDriver() #another object of WebDriver() is created
   print(driver.singleton_instance)

   WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(
     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "%s")]' % text))
   )

context.browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't nee to use `__new__`

```
class WebDriver:

    class __WebDriver:
        def __init__(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')

    driver = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not self.driver:
            WebDriver.driver = WebDriver.__WebDriver().driver


@given ("website '{url}'")
def website_opener(context,url):
    driver = WebDriver().driver
    driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Comment: but i didn't actually get self.driver line, since an inner class doesn't have "driver' field..

Comment: @VadimPopov `self.driver` in the `__init__` create it.

Answer (score 1):

Your check with `hasattr(cls,'instance')` can only return false, since your instance is called `singleton_instance`. How to do this the right way (also overriding attribute access): https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html